# Problem when move the implementation from built-in to dll

Tags: c++, linux, dll, arm

I've a function as follwing:

void function()

{

```
// open tcp port
```

}

Sorry but I can't post my source code here.

It work fine when I call this function from main, and when I try to move this function into a dll, it work okay on window and linux, but got crash on arm (signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped),
I tried to use gdb but the backtrace are insufficient information for me to trace.

```
Thread 5 "xxx" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to LWP 23448]
0x00000000600c3cf9 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000600c3cf9 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Is there anyone have experience in this case ?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: If you don't show the code there is not much one can do to help you. Sorry but I can't post my answer here. ;) You should provide a minimal example demonstrating your problem. I would guess that it is related to dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is not in code but at least you can but more information how did you build the application and the library for arm.